# Subversion Edge console won't start

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversion-edge

I can't start my subversion edge admin page or authentication page.

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/zzz/login/auth`

But i can see the data that i already have insert with tortoise application.

I can't see if the server is running, but the internet doesn't have any problem.
The last week I managed to connect to svnEdge, and now I have received this error, both in Chorme and IE10.
Did Subversion Edge have problems this weekend or i have a problem configuring the svnEdge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was due to not having started the SVN Edge server, for this you need to go  **Services** -> **Collab Subversion Edge** -> **Start**.

But the problem was not there, because he gave not to **Start** the SVN Edge served, for it had to modify the **JAVA_HOME** due to **JR6** have been configured in my absence and not being to work, to modify **jr7**
Right-click **My Computer** -> Select **Properties** -> **Advanced** Tab -> Click the **Environment Variables** button -> Then Change to a new version or create a **JAVA_HOME**.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable